# net.unix.max_dgram_qlen questions

Tags: linux, sockets, network-programming

According to the kernel documentation net.unix.max_dgram_qlen sysctl controls the maximum length of a datagram socket receive queue (for AF_UNIX/AF_LOCAL sockets that is).  I can always send 1 more than this value before send calls to that receiver start blocking.  Anyone know why?

Also, does anyone know if this was ever implemented as a socket option.  (Kind of like SO_SNDBUF corresponds to wmem_default and wmem_max).  This [thread](http://old.nabble.com/Get-rid-of--proc-sys-net-unix-max_dgram_qlen-tt5932376.html#a5932376) mentions that possibility but I can't find where anyone ever did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1., That's how it is checked:

```
static inline int unix_recvq_full(struct sock const *sk)                                        
{
    return skb_queue_len(&sk->sk_receive_queue) > sk->sk_max_ack_backlog;
}
```

That's why you can initiate one more connection than the value you had set.

2., The backlog parameter you pass to **listen()** is also used as **max_ack_backlog**. No other way exists to influence it, though.

Comment: Are you talking about datagrams or stream sockets?  My question concerns datagrams.  Are you saying that both max_dgram_qlen (for datagrams) or the backlog parameter (for stream sockets) map to max_ack_backlog?  My question isn't so much how it is checked (that seems clear), but rather why is it checked that why?  Why > instead of >=?  It's hard to believe there isn't a reason since it's counter-intuitive.

Comment: listen() is only for stream sockets, so for datagram your only option is the sysctl knob.  You're right about the check being counter-intuitive, but that's I guess for historical reasons.